# Is there a RSS feed to subscribe to in order to receive information on new LibreOffice releases?

Tags: libreoffice

I am looking for a public RSS feed that informs me about new releases of LibreOffice.

Is anyone aware of a respective RSS feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Press Releases – The Document Foundation Blog](https://blog.documentfoundation.org/blog/category/press-releases/feed/) feed announces new releases of LibreOffice, LibreOffice development news, LibreOffice conference news, and other topics related to LibreOffice. If you are using Firefox you can subscribe to the RSS feed by clicking the *Subscribe Now* button on the webpage or subscribe to the feed by copying the link into an RSS reader